# Android: binding to service immediately after it is started

Tags: android, service, android-service

I want to make a voice recorder app, which can record, even when the app is in background. So I implemented a service. I need to start it, and after it started immediately bound to it. As I suspect startService and bindService are asynchronous calls. And I experienced, when I make the calls after each other, sometimes bindService is called, when the service has not been properly started. How can I be sure that bindService runs only, when service has been started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following snippet to start and bind to service:

```
Intent playerIntent = new Intent(activity, PlayerService.class);
activity.startService(playerIntent);
activity.bindService(playerIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

`mConnection` is a [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) instance that receives a `onServiceConnected` callback when the service is started and bound. Any time I interact with the service, I ask the `ServiceConnection` if the service is bound.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question